# SELECT all from left, only from right only where

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, Roles, UsersInRoles and Users

I want to select all roles and a only user records where the user matches the where clause

```
    SELECT              r.*, u.UserName

    FROM                [dbo].[Roles] r

    LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[UsersInRoles ] ur
    ON                  r.Id = ur.RoleId

    LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[Users] u
    ON                  u.Id = ur.UserId

    WHERE               u.UserName = 'admin'
```

What I want is this:

RoleId, Role,      Username
1          Admin     Admin
2          Student   Null

When I include the where clause, the student role is not returned

Comment: You are selecting only where you have `u.UserName = 'admin'` and the `Student` role has `Null` for `Username`. It doesn't match the where clause to show up, does it?

Comment: I realize this, I need the where clause to only apply to the right table, not the left

Comment: I hate it when people -1 you without providing a reason. Cowards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the filter from your WHERE clause, to the join condition of your Users table:

```
SELECT              r.*, u.UserName
FROM                [dbo].[Roles] r
LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[UsersInRoles ] ur
ON                  r.Id = ur.RoleId
LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[Users] u
ON                  u.Id = ur.UserId
                AND u.UserName = 'admin'
```

This will return all records from Roles, with any matching records from UsersInRoles, but only those matching records in Users whose UserName equals 'admin'.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I just added a distinct statement to get rid of the duplicates caused by other users' records in the UsersInRoles Table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT              r.*, u.UserName

FROM                [dbo].[Roles] r

LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[UsersInRoles ] ur
ON                  r.Id = ur.RoleId

LEFT JOIN           [dbo].[Users] u
ON                  u.Id = ur.UserId

WHERE               (u.UserName = 'admin' or u.UserName is null)
```

Comment: While this returns the correct result, a more elegant way to filter the rightmost table, is to simply apply the UserName = 'admin' filter directly in the join-condition, instead of in the WHERE-clause. Check my solution below.